# Remove PHP 5.4.14

Tags: php

I want to install php 5.3.10 but I already got PHP 5.4.13.
I want to remove first existing PHP 5.4.13 then want to install new PHP 5.3.13.

How can I remove existing PHP  5.4.13??

Comment: How did you initially install it?

Comment: Sudo apt-get install PHP but I can't remove now

Comment: remove it with `sudo apt-get remove php` and then install it with `sudo apt-get install php 5.3.10`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php error comes up when I try sudo apt-get remove php

Answer (score 2):

To remove an application that was installed with apt-get, its configuration files, and dependencies, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get remove <package_name>
apt-get purge <package_name>
apt-get autoremove <package_name>
```

I believe that the right package name is `php5 libapache2-mod-php5`  But you need to check if that's it from when you installed it.

Comment: Mitch I've followed your steps but while I type php -v its showing my previous version that indicates its still not removed...

Comment: If I type php -v shows my version is PHP 5.4.14 (cli) but using this package name is not working and comes up error unable to locate....please help me out..

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge <package_name>`.  Also do `sudo apt-file search <package_name>` just to make sure that there are no more php packages, if there is need to remove them all.